# Wine - Incompatible Operating System

Tags: wine

So I installed Wine on my machine to use smartflix on ubuntu, but I keep getting this error saying "incompatible operating system: This program cannot run on Windows XP or before; it requires a later version of windows". Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 24):

Open a terminal window and run

`winecfg`

A window will pop up. Change "Windows version" from Windows XP to a later version of Windows (I don't know which version your program requires). Click "OK".

Comment: I would like to add that generally you need to add the executable to the Application Settings box, then choose for the app what version of Windows it is supposed to run under.  +1